arm cbz instruction with apparent always non-zero register value
While analyzing a 3d-printer firmware (From Flashforge) with ghidra, I stumbled upon following arm thumb code:
...
LAB_0012a734:   XREF[2]:     0012a808(j), 0012a810(j)  
        0012a734 06 9b           ldr        r3,[sp,#local_18]
        0012a736 a3 f1 0c 00     sub.w      r0,r3,#0xc
        0012a73a a0 42           cmp        r0,r4
        0012a73c 69 d1           bne        LAB_0012a812
...
...
LAB_0012a806:   XREF[1]:     0012a85a(j)  
        0012a806 00 2a           cmp        r2,#0x0
        0012a808 94 dc           bgt        LAB_0012a734
        0012a80a 05 a9           add        r1,sp,#0x14
        0012a80c f9 f6 f6 ea     blx        <EXTERNAL>::std::basic_string<char,std::char_t
        0012a810 90 e7           b          LAB_0012a734
LAB_0012a812:   XREF[1]:     0012a73c(j)  
        0012a812 43 f2 40 72     movw       r2,#0x3740
        0012a816 c0 f2 02 02     movt       r2,#0x2
        0012a81a 8a b1           cbz        r2,LAB_0012a840
        0012a81c 04 3b           subs       r3,#0x4
        0012a81e bf f3 5f 8f     dmb        #0x1f
LAB_0012a822:   XREF[1]:     0012a82e(j)  
        0012a822 53 e8 00 2f     ldrex      r2,[r3,#0x0]
        0012a826 51 1e           subs       r1,r2,#0x1
        0012a828 43 e8 00 14     strex      r4,r1,[r3,#0x0]
        0012a82c 00 2c           cmp        r4,#0x0
        0012a82e f8 d1           bne        LAB_0012a822
        0012a830 bf f3 5f 8f     dmb        #0x1f
...

The cbz instruction at 0012a81a compares register value r2 and branches to LAB_0012a840 if the value is zero.
In the case from above r2 gets the value 0x23740 at 12a812/12a816 and thus will never be zero. The code is also not self-modifying. The movw/movt instructions are not skipped either, since there is no branch instruction which would go directly to 12a81a.
I verified the instructions with a debugger, but since it looks so obvious, it does exactly what is programmed. r2 is never zero.
Might this be a safeguard against a nullpointer (Which can obviously never happen though)?
So my question is, does anyone know what the purpose of the cbz instruction could be?

"there is no branch instruction which would go directly to 12a81a": How did you determine that?  Because that's by far the most likely explanation.  Note that in principle, it could be an indirect branch.

To determine that there is no branch instruction to 12a81a, I searched for any reference containing that address. Furthermore ghidra would have placed a label to that address if it would have analyzed accordingly, which it did not.

Okay, but that wouldn't necessarily find an indirect branch. Or it could be code built with a non-optimizing or poorly optimizing compiler. Or it's handwritten asm, and maybe the preceding code used to compute r2 in some fashion, such that it could be zero. Then they changed the preceding code but forgot to remove the now-redundant conditional branch. I think you'll have to analyze the code more broadly, and get an overall sense of what it is doing, to find out. I don't think there's any way to guess from seeing the snippet in isolation.

Re "null pointer safeguard": is the value in r2 actually used as a pointer?

r2 (0x23740) possibly points to a memory address, but it does not seem to be used during further execution, as you can see.

The cbz makes no sense as the value is set to non-zero.  It is trying to exchange the r2 value with an memory pointer.  This is 'lock free' strex/ldrex.  Most likely these lock free primitives are implemented with in-line assembler that is not properly annotated and the compiler is confused and leaves dead code.  For instance,  r2 is destroyed by the ldrex, so loop backs do not make sense, as Nate suggests and I originally thought.  Really, I trust the tool is not a good reason.  You could only know with the original source, but I think above gives good rationale.
